# sending blob data in json file to android app

Tags: php, android, sql, json, symfony

i'm trying to send an image in a json file to an android app here is my code:

```
public function allUserCarsAction()
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $UId = $request->request->get('UId');

        $em = $this -> getDoctrine();
        $id = $em -> getRepository("OBCarsTest2Bundle:user") ->findOneById($UId);
        $UserCars = $em -> getRepository("OBCarsTest2Bundle:cars") ->findByidUser($id);

        $a = 0;

        if($UserCars != Null)
        {
            foreach($UserCars as $car)
            {
                $ModelId = $em -> getRepository("OBCarsTest2Bundle:models")->findOneById($car->getModels());
                $BrandsId = $em -> getRepository("OBCarsTest2Bundle:brands")->findOneById($car->getBrands());

                if($ModelId!=Null && $BrandsId != Null)
                {
                    $infoCars = array ('name'=>$BrandsId->getCarBrand(),
                               'model'=>$ModelId->getCarModel(),
                               'carvin'=>$car->getVin(),
                               'price'=>$car->getPrice(),
                               'currency'=>$car->getCurrency(),
                               'pic'=>$pic=($car->getPic()));

                    $userCar[$a] = $infoCars;
                    $a++;
                }
            }
            $Cars = array ('cars'=>$userCar);
            $CarsSent = json_encode($Cars);
        }
        else
            $CarsSent = '{"CarsSent":0}';

        return new Response($CarsSent);
    }
```

that is the entity where the image is configured:

```
     /**
     * @var blob
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="$pic", type="blob")
     */
    private $pic;

    /**
     * Set pic
     *
     * @param string $pic
     * @return cars
     */
    public function setPic($pic)
    {
        $this->pic = $pic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pic
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPic()
    {
        return $this->pic;
    }
```

but my partner is having this message when he tries to get the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>An Error Occurred: Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Oops! An Error Occurred</h1>
        <h2>The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".</h2>

        <div>
            Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred.
            We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i put :"'pic'=>$pic=($car->getPic()));" in comment he receives all the cars without the images.

How can i send the image within the json file?

PS I have spent 3 days trying to solve this but didn't get anywhere. I tried to use this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to encode it in `base64`.

Given that `$car->getPic()` holds actual binary data, you would need:

```
$pic=$car->getPic();
$infoCars = array (
    'name'=>$BrandsId->getCarBrand(),
   'model'=>$ModelId->getCarModel(),
   'carvin'=>$car->getVin(),
   'price'=>$car->getPrice(),
   'currency'=>$car->getCurrency(),
   'pic'=> base64_encode($pic) // <-- THIS
);
```

Depending of the purpose of the image, the other side would need to decode. I know CSS allows to set `background-image` to `base64` encoded value, however, I am not familiar with `Android`'s capabilities.

Hope this helps...

Comment: i am getting it encoded and i am saving it as it is. Is it the way i'm saving the image wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the data going `Symfony2 -> Android` or is it vice versa?

Comment: So, does `$car->getPic()` return expected data? Try calling this action with  browser and echo-int the content of the `$pic`...

Comment: Hey daroum, I see you accepted the answer. Can you tell us how did you manage to resolve the issue?